# Uncaught Exception: Error: Cannot find module 'pcsclite'

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, pcsc

This is the first time I'm building something with Electron.
Now, I read everything there is in the FAQ section of this module ([node-pcsclite](https://github.com/pokusew/node-pcsclite)) and the "Can I use this library in my Electron app?" section.
I tried everything from the Electron docs ([Using Native Node Modules](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules)). The only thing I didn't try is "Manually building for a custom build of Electron" - since I'm not running a custom Electron build.

Things I tried:

- Different versions of almost everything.
- Tried doing everything on OSX and Linux.
- Older node and npm versions.
- Different electron headers.
- Checked that the cpu target architectures are matched.
- Tried packaging the app with electron-builder and running it on OSX.
- Tried re-configuring the electron-builder with options such as buildDependenciesFromSource and npmRebuild set to true.
- Removed node_modules, removed cache and tried re-installing everything a few times.
- Tried manually copying the "pcsclite.node" from node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite/build/Release" into the build folder of the project and repackaging it again - still getting the same error.

No success. 
I keep getting the following Uncaught Exception whenever I run the app (whether with "electron ." (npm start) or as a fully packaged app with electron-builder).

```
Error: Cannot find module 'pcsclite'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/flackjap/Code/vozzi/electronic-service-book/first-test/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:43:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:510:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/flackjap/Code/vozzi/electronic-service-book/first-test/main.js:4:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/flackjap/Code/vozzi/electronic-service-book/first-test/main.js:144:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:693:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:704:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
```

I'm not sure if this is the general problem with building native modules or just a problem with this module specifically. I tried googling and didn't find enough relatable issues, so it seemed to me that the problem might actually be with this module specifically.

This is my package.json:

```
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "distt": "electron-builder",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.5",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.4",
    "@pokusew/pcsclite": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "buildDependenciesFromSource": true,
    "nodeGypRebuild": false,
    "npmRebuild": true,
    "appId": "electron.vozzi.app",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "squirrel",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  }
}
```

The only thing I find a bit suspicious is the folder structure for this module, since it has two parent folders (node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite/...), and that maybe some paths are misconfigured, but I don't know where to look or how to debug. I did however see at some Stackoverflow comments that people are manually configuring some module paths in some cases, but I'm not sure how should I approach this, or even if I should be doing that.

Comment: Can you post you script as well?

Comment: @Ashvin777 No need. The moment you asked for the code, I asked myself - "What could possibly go wrong in the code? I just copy pasted it from the README.md ... and it only gets stuck at the require/import level. Hmm wait a minute...". I just changed the path to "@pokusew/pcsclite", which was actually the correct name for the module itself, but I copied the wrong one from the README.md which wasn't updated :)